# Count number of rows where value in a column is not a part of a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set, let's say like this:

Item Name

Apple

Carrot

Carrot

Pear

Pear

Pineapple

Radish

Orange

Orange

Pineapple

Pineapple

and I also have a LIST like this:

List of Items:

Apple

Orange

Pineapple

How to write a formula that will count how many rows in the dataset have a value that is NOT a part of the list? ... so in this case 5...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just take the number which are in the list away from the total:-

```
=COUNTA($A$2:$A$20)-SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$20,$B$2:$B$20))
```

assuming data items in column A and list in column B.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a named range of the list.
Mark your list of items and in the "name box" write LIST.

Now if the long list is in column A, then in column B write the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1;LIST;1;FALSE);1)
```

It will find the match in the LIST if it excists, if not write "1".

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that in this case I cannot add an "assist" column

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIFS(rng,"<>Apple",rng,"<>Orange",rng,"<>Pineapple")
```

Assuming your named range for the long column is rng.

Obviously this works best if your short list is very short.

Comment: that's a bit too "hard coded" .. i need to be able to quickly and easily manipulate the list

Comment: then use Tom's answer. however, if you should have a data set where a large proportion of the values are for example "Standard" and the rest are exceptions, this method counts the outliers with minimal processing power (helpful for extra large data sets)